# Проблема рендеренга BottomAppBar и TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет!

Возникает проблема с рендерингом активити. Как понимаю, что-то не так с `BottomAppBar`, но никакого решения найти не получается. Также ругается на `TextInputLayout` (в новом проекте проблем с `TextInputLayout` проблем нет).

Очистка кэша, синхронизация с gradle, переустанавливала студию - не помогает
Использую `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'`

Раннее отображалось всё корректно, но в какой-то момент решило поломаться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ui.event.AddEventFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Выберете"
            android:textColor="@color/md_theme_light_onSurface"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:singleSelection="true">
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Suggestion.Elevated"
                app:chipIconVisible="true"
                app:chipIcon="@drawable/noto_v1_cat_face"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Заметка"
            android:textColor="@color/md_theme_light_onSurface"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chipGroup" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/noteField"
            style="?attr/textInputFilledStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:labelFor="@id/note"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/md_theme_light_surfaceVariant"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteView">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/note"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/mood"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:textColor="@color/md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_event" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="save data"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Motion easing theme attribute must be an @interpolator resource for ?attr/motionEasing*Interpolator attributes or a string for ?attr/motionEasing* attributes.
at com.google.android.material.motion.MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(MotionUtils.java:74)
at com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.onLayoutChild(HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.java:121)
at com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar$Behavior.onLayoutChild(BottomAppBar.java:1453)
at com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar$Behavior.onLayoutChild(BottomAppBar.java:1309)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout_Original(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23143)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23143)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23143)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23143)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout_Original(View.java:23143)
at android.view.View_Delegate.layout(View_Delegate.java:91)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:378)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связана с использованием версии Electric Eel, в Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 2 работает без нареканий

В гите есть обсуждение по этому поводу

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3007